# Using Geo Tracking and an SQL query

Tags: mysql, search, geolocation, geocoding

I'm building a database where the user will be able to type in a search field for what they are looking for, and I need the results to list in a manner where those closest to the user will show first, and work their way further from the user's current location.

So I'm looking for a method to include (factor in) Geo location with a query. The database will have a multitude of fields that will be searched through, including the location of each.

This whole process will be much like that of Google's Map location searches (ie. Searching for "Restaurants near me").

I've tried googling for this answer, I've asked on other forums, and I've searched stackoverflow and have yet to find help in accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL Spatial Extensions to order results by distance

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html

That allows you to do queries like

```
SELECT name, AsText(location), SQRT(POW( ABS( X(location) - X(@center)), 2) + POW( ABS(Y(location) - Y(@center)), 2 )) AS distance 
FROM Points 
WHERE Intersects( location, GeomFromText(@bbox) ) 
AND SQRT(POW( ABS( X(location) - X(@center)), 2) + POW( ABS(Y(location) - Y(@center)), 2 )) < @radius 
ORDER BY distance;
```

http://howto-use-mysql-spatial-ext.blogspot.com/

Comment: So how do I get the visitor's location to compare with the database locations? Or are you explaining that and it's going over my head... sorry.

Comment: This example (and Spatial Extensions in general) work accurately only on an infinite flat surface. They may be good enough for some geolocation uses but will give you completely wrong results if your locations are near the poles or on different sides of the 180th meridian (and close to it).

Comment: All of the locations will be within the continental US.

Comment: @Vatev: Presumably you're not going to show a Starbucks in Alaska to a visitor in Florida :-)  Spacial Extensions should be accurate enough for the use case.

Comment: @Justgrant2009: Getting the geolocation is a different question :-)  Some browsers present a Geolocation API to figure out where the person is located (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API).  For browsers that do not support the API (or if the user disallows your website from learning the location) you can fall back on geolocating the IP address, though that is sometimes quite inaccurate (about 85% of the time you will be within 30 miles but sometimes you will be *way* off).  Check out MaxMind.com

Comment: @EricJ. Thanks, that's actually quite helpful! I'll be delving into that and seeing what I can get running.  Thank you!  If I need more help, I know where to find it!